# Help? How to glitter a photo canvas

Tags: diamond-dust

I want to glitter a photo canvas. Just an all over sparkle over the picture.

How do you diamond dust a canvas?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to A&C! Can you please **[edit]** to just one question that you are most interested in getting an answer to -- what method would be better (and let us know your criteria: easiest, cheapest, prettiest?) or how to diamond dust? Take a look at our **[tour]** to learn why we like questions to focus on just one question at a time. (Feel free to ask more than one! We love questions!) Thanks :)

Comment: As in, you want to apply glitter after the photo has been printed on it?

Answer (score 2):

The method I use is a clear glaze which also acts as a strong adhesive. And, coincidently, the best product I have found is something called Diamond Glaze which is a type of varnish. It is used predominantly in card & jewellery making.

There are lots of manufacturers and it seems universally available. When it dries it provides a completely clear varnish with virtually no opacity or hue. And it is very strong adhesive. Below is an example of one manufacturer (no connection):

[image: Judikins Diamond Glaze]

[Judikins Diamond Glaze on Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_2_9?url=search-alias%3Darts-crafts&field-keywords=diamond%20glaze&sprefix=Diamond%20g%2Caps%2C194&crid=1HA2K3FLLXT06)

As it is water soluble, when wet, you can also add inks or dyes to provide different effects. But once dry, about 2-3 hours, it is exceptionally difficult to remove and provides about as permanent adhesive as you can find.

You do need to be careful when applying to media that is water soluble, as it can bleed. So it is best to test it out first. But I've successfully used it on fully dried acrylic paints without issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your photo is printed on a home inkjet or laser printer, a liquid medium will cause the image to bleed.

On a professionally printed image just make sure to not overwork any liquid medium. Try using a Popsicle stick to evenly distribute a thin layer of the glue quickly.

You might also try a gloss or matt spray finish. [Krylon makes one specifically for digitally printed photos](http://www.krylon.com/products/preserve-it-digital-photo-paper-protectant/) but I'm sure it would work for professional photos as well.

Spray a very light coat of finish and then lightly sprinkle your diamond dust. The Krylon says it's dry to the touch in about 10 minutes. This should give you plenty of time to apply the amount of diamond dust you want. (You don't have to have a wet surface for the diamond dust to adhere, just a lightly tacky one.)

Keep in mind, even though something says "dries clear" doesn't mean it won't affect the intensity of the image. You are putting an additional barrier (albeit super thin) on top of your image. Light now has to travel through that layer to reach the image--some dullness or distortion may result.

Do not use spray glue. That stuff is a nightmare and not intended for delicate jobs.

Comment: I would test homemade laser prints, as most of them do not react to many liquids.